# Script for File Upload using Ruby/Capybara/autoIT

Tags: file-upload, capybara, autoit

I'm trying to upload a file using Capybara script. I got some help from the below link and I'm trying to use the `autoIT` option that specified in the below link:

[Testing HTML5 File Upload with Capybara/Selenium Webdriver - Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382367/testing-html5-file-upload-with-capybara-selenium-webdriver-ruby/23275548#23275548)

From the above page, I have a question on the below two lines:

```
find_field(<<upload_file_id>>).click

system("<<full_path>>\\file_upload.exe \"#{<<file_path>>}\" \"File Upload\"")
```

---

Thanks to the script, I have created an .exe with the given code and gave the above two lines in order to upload the file, but it is giving a syntax error.

What is "File Upload" in the above syntax? Is this the name of the file that I would like to upload? I tried so many ways (forward/backward slashes), but it is returning `Syntax error (syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' (SyntaxError))`. Here is what my syntax is. Please suggest and let me know what I'm missing. Appreciate suggestions in this regard. Any example with a specific file name in the syntax will really helps.

```
system("C:/Cucumber/cucumberdemo/features/file_upload.exe/"#     
{C:/Cucumber/cucumberdemo/Capybara.PNG}\"\File Upload\"")

system("C:\Cucumber\cucumberdemo\features\file_upload.exe\"#
{C:\Cucumber\cucumberdemo}\"\"Capybara.PNG\"")

system("C:/Cucumber/cucumberdemo/features//file_upload.exe/"#
{C:/Cucumber/cucumberdemo}/"/"Capybara.PNG/"")

system("C:/Cucumber/cucumberdemo/features/file_upload.exe/"#
{C:/Cucumber/cucumberdemo/Capybara.PNG}/"")
```

Also, will the `System` command also click the "Open" button from the dialog box or do I need to write a separate script for that?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use **attach_file** method from Capybara?

[attach_file method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions%3aattach_file)

Answer (score 0):

try with this 
system("C:/Cucumber/cucumberdemo/features/file_upload.exe /"#
{"C:/Cucumber/cucumberdemo/Capybara.png"}\ "\File Upload\"")
file path also should placed in double quotes that u forgot like

## {"file path"}